# Corda ledger prune possible?

Tags: database, blockchain, corda

Is it possible to 'prune' the Corda ledger ?
Participants could agree to remove all consumed states prior to a certain point in time. That could be necessary if the database becomes too big, like several Gb or Tb ?

Comment: Here is something you might be interested in: https://www.r3.com/videos/vault-recycler-right-to-be-forgotten-r3/

Answer (score 1):

Remove consumed states on the basis of time doesn't seem to be a good solution. You could only remove fully consumed transaction trees, since Corda contract verification involves walking the entire blockchain which is necessary to prove the provenance of the inputs to a transaction.

You could look at this video to know more about it: https://www.r3.com/videos/vault-recycler-right-to-be-forgotten-r3/